# Solutions to $x^p+y^q = z^r$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there any $(p,q,r)$ with $\gcd(p,q,r) = 1$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r} < 1$ for which we know that the only integer solutions (not necessarily primitive) to the equation $x^p+y^q=z^r$ have $xyz = 0$? More generally, is there any $(p,q,r)$ as above such that we can describe explicitly all the solutions (not necessarily primitive) to $x^p+y^q=z^r$?

Comment: Source of the problem? Thoughts?

Comment: I've been wondering about this for a while and haven't found anything satisfactory in the literature -- there is a lot about primitive solutions, but close to nothing on how to characterise non-primitive solutions.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/QR8.pdf) is of your interest.  But odds are you have already read it. This is very close to the [Fermat-Catalan conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture), but you are asking for coprime powers, not coprime bases. In particular, a quite boring solution is $1^x+2^3=3^2$, choosing $x$ appropiately.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

There are no $p,q,r$ meeting the given conditions for which we know the only solutions have $xyz=0$, because there are no $p,q,r$ for which the only solutions have $xyz=0$.

Given $p,q,r$, define $c$ by $1+2^q=c$. Then $c^s+2^qc^s=c^{s+1}$. Choose $s$ so that $s=pqt$ for some $t$, and $s+1=ru$ for some $u$ --- this can be done, since $p,q,r$ are coprime. Then $$(c^{qt})^p+(2c^{pt})^q=(c^u)^r$$ So, you always have nonzero solutions.